# Convergence/Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+n^2+\cdots+n^n}{n^{n+2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+n^2+\cdots+n^n}{n^{n+2}}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^{n+2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+n+\cdots+n}{n^{n+2}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+n^2+\cdots+n^n}{n^{n+2}}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^n+n^n+\cdots+n^n}{n^{n+2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n+1}}{n^{n+2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$

But is still does not help to conclude about converges/diverges

Comment: You can for example use that $n + n^2 + \ldots + n^n$ is a geometrical series which sums to $n\frac{n^n-1}{n-1}$

Comment: @Winther sorry for the qeustion but how did we get $n\frac{n^n-1}{n-1}$? isn't the formula is $\frac{1}{1-r}$?

Comment: $\frac {1}{1-r}$ is for infinite series with $|r|<1$, for finite series @Winther formula is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your approach work if you do the following:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^{n+2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+n+\cdots+n}{n^{n+2}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+n^2+\cdots+n^n}{n^{n+2}}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{\color{red}{n-1}}+n^{\color{red}{n-1}}+\cdots+n^{\color{red}{n-1}}+n^n}{n^{n+2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n-1}(n-1)+n^n}{n^{n+2}}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n}+n^n-n^{n-1}}{n^{n+2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have: $n+n^2+\cdots + n^n = n(1+n+n^2+\cdots + n^{n-1})= \dfrac{n(n^n-1)}{n-1}\implies \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n+n^2+\cdots n^n}{n^{n+2}} < \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}$, and this one converges .

Comment: Could you have used the sum 1/(n^2) with the limit test to prove convergence?

Answer (score 1):

If $n>1$ we have $n+n^2+\dots + n^n=\frac{n^{n+1}-1}{n-1}-1\leq\frac{n^{n+1}}{n-1}\leq 2n^{n}$

So $\frac{n+n^2+\dots + n^n}{n^{n+2}}\leq n^{-2}$

Therefore $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n+n^2+\cdots+n^n}{n^{n+2}}\leq\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-2}<\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Easy with *equivalents* (this requires the general term to have a constant sign) and some computation:
$$n+n^2+\dots+n^n=\frac{n(n^n-1)}{n-1}\sim_\infty n^n$$
so
$$\frac{n+n^2+\cdots+n^n}{n^{n+2}}\sim_\infty\frac{n^n}{n^{n+2}}=\frac1{n^2},$$
which converges.